# Execute a Terminal command based on receiving an email in Thunderbird on a Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, thunderbird

I would like to have a Terminal command run when I receive an email in Thunderbird from a certain address with a certain subject. Is there a way to do this on a Mac?

Comment: What does your code currently look like for receiving emails?

Comment: I currently only have code for the Terminal command. I was hoping to rely on an email program to take care of the receiving email part. It looks like only Mail can do such a thing? I'm a Thunderbird user and I know of no such way to set up a rule :(

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps another site on the stack exchange network would be more useful.

Comment: Ok, I apologize. I'm new to Stackexchange so I'm still getting used to everything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to look into [Thunderbird extension development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird). What you want to do is definitely possible though. It might be a little more work than VBA scripting in Outlook, but on the bright side, you can use JS instead of VBA, and you'll be able to develop Firefox extensions too by the time you're done. =P

Comment: What you could do is to write a cron job to check the contents of the Thunderbird .msf file for new messages from that sender and run the command if found. I won't say that this is an elegant or perfect solution though. As for doing this inside Thunderbird, I am not sure if it could be done.

Comment: +1 This question definitely has become very important recently, since the Thunderbird guys managed to break the most important functionality when integrating their own PGP solution (for example, we can't permanently decrypt inbound encrypted messages any more). I already have a shell script which can decrypt .eml messages, and I came across this question when researching how I could trigger that script from within Thunderbird.

Answer (score 3):

The FiltaQuilla extension allows to run any script as part of a Thunderbird filter:

```
If From = foo@bar.com
Then Run script /home/user/bin/command.sh
```

See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/

Comment: +1 This answer hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

In your Mail Application, create a Rule (*Preferences » Rules*) which executes AppleScript if the subject matches.

If you want to do it in terminal, look into "procmail" and possibly "fetchmail".

Comment: Thunderbird has AppleScript integration?